# Can we create same name of PushButton in two different Ribbons?

Tags: revit-api, revit

I just want to ask can we create the same name of PushButton in two different Ribbons with Revit API 2020?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see no reason why not. Please go ahead, try it out, and let us know what you find out. One out of many possible starting points for experimentation is provided by the [2_Revit_UI_API sample labs](https://github.com/jeremytammik/AdnRevitApiLabsXtra/tree/master/2_Revit_UI_API)  in the [ADN Revit API Training Labs including Xtra](https://github.com/jeremytammik/AdnRevitApiLabsXtra).